# Keras - How to get GRU cell state?

Tags: keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, keras-layer

For LSTM we can retrieve last output and last cell state as below

```
outputs, state_h, state_c= LSTM(lstm_dim, return_sequences=True, return_state=True)(inputs)
```

where state_h is the last sequence of outputs; outputs[-1]=state_h and state_c is **the last CELL STATE of LSTM**.

But with GRU it does not have such an option but only gives which is equivalent to state_h. How do I get state_c the last cell state from Keras GRU?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no internal memory in `GRU`, which means there is no `cell state`.

`GRU`, in general directly operate on the hidden state to get the output value. For most of the purpose, `GRU` has the same performance as that of `LSTM`, while with less computation (less number of parameters).

Feel free to ask question.

Comment: Just let me clarify something more. I am looking at the structures of LSTM and GRU cells. For LSTM, ht is the output for at time t and Ct is the cell state? and for GRU only has ht so you are saying there is no cell state and it is strictly applied to the Keras? I have been thinking the cell state would mean some weights in the cell used to proceed the calculations for LSTM and GRU. My guess is that latter, which is my thought, is wrong?

Comment: Then if that so, how can I get the sequences of cell states from Keras LSTM layer? Does it require some custom modification of the layer?

Comment: When you use `return_sequence`, it return the output as well as hidden state for each cell, even it has been rolled. This is useful, when you are attaching other layer of LSTM or GRU, which can be benefitted from those hidden infomation. For more, you can refer to [link](https://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/)

Comment: You don't need any custom layer, for your task. Please read keras [documentation](https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/) for that.

Comment: I'm sorry, what you answered is not true. return_sequences only returns the outputs of the LSTM sequences,  but not cell states of LSTM sequences. And even with return_state it only gives the last cell state of LSTM sequences. I wanted to know each cell state of sequences. I even tested the sample codes to see what they give.